# using session to store data from anonymous user

Tags: django, django-models, django-sessions

in my django app, I have a user wishlist feature. I want that an anonymous user can add a product to his wishlist.

```
models.py

class User_Wishlist(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, null =True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Products, null=True)


# some Products model

views.py
# to add an item from the user wishlist

def add_userwl(request, id):
    products = Products.objects.filter(id__iexact=id)
    product = products[0]
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        userwlt = get_sl(request, request.user) #gets the auth user wishlist
        userwlt.products.add(product)
        sl_products = userwlt.products.all()
    else:
        if "wl_user" in request.session:
            wl_user = request.session["wl_user"]
        else:
            wl_user = User_Wishlist(created_by = request.user) #here lies the problem!
            request.session["wl_user"] = wl_user

        wl_user.products.add(product)
        wl_products = wl_user.products.all()

    return render_to_response('getsl.html', {
       'wl_products':wl_products
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Error: Cannot assign  "": "User_Wishlist.created_by" must be a "User" instance.

So, it can't create a wishlist for an anon user. Also if I just do wl_user = User_Wishlist(), it can't access the manytomany field 'products' without assigning a user id.

Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

p.s: I also want to save this user wishlist once the anon user signs up, but thats a later problem

Answer (score 2):

Your concept of an anonymous user seems wrong. If you wish to bound data to a certain 'user' you will have to create an 'user' for them. Otherwise whenever the session expires or the 'user' resets his or her browser's cache the data is gone.

Now how an 'user' is defined is entirely up to you. It could be a 'cart' or a 'customer' or anything else. There's no reason you can't use a different abstraction then the one provided by Django's auth module.

Most sites that implement this properly allow your not-so-much 'anonymous' session to be bound to an optional account at some point (which might as well be an oauth or openid solution).

Comment: thanks for the reply! so I created a user, user = User(username = request.session.session_key)..dont know if giving the session_key as username or id is apt, just did it for the time being to test. Works well!
How do you think I can create a User object, keeping in mind that later I want this data to be saved when the user signs up.

Answer (score 0):

The much simpler solution is to require that a wishlis is tied to *either* a user object or a session object. So allow for those fields to be null and implement logic that favours the user object.